# java stream doesn't compile with Locale's method function, why?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, locale

I've got this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US", "WIN");//ok
System.out.println(locale.getLanguage());//ok
Stream<Locale> sl = Stream.of(Locale.getAvailableLocales());//ok
Map<String, List<Locale>> map = sl.collect(
    Collectors.partitioningBy(l->l.getLanguage().equals("en")));//error
```

> Compilation error: Cannot resolve method "getLanguage()".

How to fix it?

Comment: What do you think `partitioningBy` does? What do you think should be stored in `Map<String, List<Locale>>`? What would the values be in that map? Why do you think so?

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy(java.util.function.Predicate)):  partitioningBy returns a Collector that produces a `Map<Boolean, List<T>>`.

Comment: A word of advice, a lot of your recent questions have been poorly received. The thing I think is missing from a lot of them is _why_. You dump a piece of code with an error message, but never explain why you think that piece of code should work. Half the time, if you just asked yourself that and followed the thread, you'd be able to answer these questions yourself.

Comment: @Troskyvs: Do you want a map with key as `String` with value "en" and value of type `List<Locale>` with value as list of english locales?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to group the locales by language then use `groupingBy` instead of `partitioningBy` :

```
Stream<Locale> sl = Stream.of(Locale.getAvailableLocales());
Map<String,List<Locale>> localsPerLanguage = sl.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Locale::getLanguage));
System.out.println(localsPerLanguage.get("fr"));
```